# python3 traceback error

Tags: terminal, linux-mint, python, command-not-found

Whenever I mistype any command in terminal instead of getting `Error:Command not found` I get this python message error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 631, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 616, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 284, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 260, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/site.py", line 250, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sysconfig.py", line 580, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sysconfig.py", line 530, in get_config_vars
    _init_posix(_CONFIG_VARS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/sysconfig.py", line 403, in _init_posix
    from _sysconfigdata import build_time_vars
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/_sysconfigdata.py", line 6, in <module>
    from _sysconfigdata_m import *
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

I know that after installing python3.x and trying to make it my default interpreter this error has gone this way.

```
$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Linux Mint 14 Nadia
Release:    14
```

`/usr/lib/command-not-found` is working well also.

Can I get back to my default python version ? simply I did

```
sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/bin/python
```

is it enough to get 2.7 as default interpreter ?

Any idea how to get rid off this hell message error ?

Comment: No one is there to make this problem solved yet :(

Comment: @ultrasawblade ,Have you any idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

Altering the default Python interpreter in a Ubuntu derived distribution is a Bad Idea. Very many system utilities expect `python` to resolve to the expected version and get very unhappy when it doesn't.

Better would be (obviously shell dependent):

```
export PATH="${HOME}/bin:${PATH}"
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 $HOME/bin/python
```

making it **your** default interpreter but leaving the system utilities as they expect.

**added in response to comment**

My first guess as to why this didn't work is that you didn't completely clean up the changes you made.

```
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/python
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
```

Should clear up the changes you reported here and restore the distribution default Python interpreter to be the system-wide default.

Then, remove your user alias that I suggested you make above:

```
rm $HOME/bin/python
```

And check if you still get the Python traceback when a shell command is not found. If you still get the traceback, I can't think of a standard mechanism that would cause that to happen. Therefore you'll need to give us more information about what shell you are using (presumably bash) and add the output of the commands

```
complete | grep python
alias | grep python
python -V
```

to your question.

Comment: making 2.7 default interpreter when call python in terminal doesn't rid this message off !! just changing used version !!Then no way to get out of this problem ?

Comment: sorry for late response....but I did all steps you've mentioned and I can confirm that the problem still out there :( !, Any body has solved such this before successfully ?

Comment: for commands you asked for the output, first two no output there just succeeded the last one `python -V` gives `Python 2.7.3`

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in the ubuntu distribution, as discussed on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446220/linux-weird-python-output) and [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python3.3/+bug/1192890).

The fix is to patch your `/etc/bash.bashrc` file, changing the line `python /usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1` to `usr/lib/command-not-found -- $1`.